# Reference for real analytic manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, manifolds

I'm trying to find a reference for some introduction to real analytic manifolds. I'm especially interested in the fact, that the set of regular points of an analytic function $F \colon M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is open dense on a real analytic manifold $M$. 
By a regular point, I mean that the differential $d_xF \colon T_xM \to \mathbb{R}^n$ has maximal rank in $M$.

Comment: Can you do the equidimensional case when M is a ball in some euclidean space?

Comment: @zhw. unfortunately, I don't know how do it. Passing to charts I should only have to show that $f \colon N:=(0,1)^m\times 0_k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ has full rank on an open and dense subset for $f$ real analytic. So if $x$ is a singular point with rank $l$, I could try to show that there is no open neighborhood $V$ in $N$ around $x$, such that all elements of $V$ are singular with rank $l$. But I don't see how to produce a contradiction by assuming the existence of $V$.

Comment: The hypothesis should assume that M is connected and f is non constant, right?

Comment: Well, you are right. Otherwise it is clear, that it isn't true...

Comment: Suppose $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is real analytic and equal to $0$ on some open ball. Then $f\equiv 0.$ Do you know this?

Comment: I thought already , that I have to use this fact. But I'm not sure how to use this uniqueness of real analytic extension.

Comment: Wait a second. What if $f(x,y) = (x,0)$?

Comment: Again I forgot to assume that $f$ has full rank in at least one point. Instead of full rank we should assume the set of point, such that the rank is maximal in $M$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\overline R$ be the closure of the set of points where $dF_x$ has full rank. If this is not everything, pick a point $x \in \partial \overline R$. Pick a real analytic chart around this point $x$; because the partial derivatives of real analytic functions are real analytic, $dF$ is real analytic. Supposing for notational convenience that $\dim M =n$ (though there is no reason to make this assumption), $\det(dF)$ is also an analytic function. Because it is nonzero somewhere, it must be nonzero on a dense open set (in this chart) - otherwise there will be a point for which $\det(dF)$ vanishes in a small open set around it, and hence $dF$ vanishes everywhere by the identity theorem, contradicting the choice $x \in \partial \overline R$.

Note that there was no point here where we needed the codomain to be $\Bbb R^n$ as opposed to some other analytic manifold.